# Can't load templates with jinja2

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, sanic

I have the following project,

```
APP
|-static
  |-templates
    |-file.html
|-blueprints
  |-blueprint1.py
  |-blueprint2.py
|-app.py
```

Each blueprint file has various `sanic` routes that I want to render a template when called.

I have tried putting the following in each `blueprint` file,

```
template_env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader('APP', 'static/templates'),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])
)
```

only to get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'APP'`

Substituting `APP` with `blueprints`gives me the error `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType`

I have also tried using a `FileSystemLoader` like this,

```
template_loader = FileSystemLoader(searchpath="../static/templates")
template_env = Environment(loader=template_loader)
```

and load the template I need `template = template_env.get_template('file.html')`

But I get a `template not found` when visiting the url.

Directly trying to render my template with,

```
with open('..static/templates/file.html') as file:
    template = Template(file.read())
```

again results in a `file not found` error.

What is the best way to use `jinja` templates in my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this i created a project in witch i render a value to jinja template and it's work fine you can take a look at this i hope will be helpfull:
this is the tree of the project :

```
.
├── app.py
└── static
    └── templates
        └── template.html

2 directories, 2 files
```

here is the template.html:

```
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
  <p>{{ value }}!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the app.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import jinja2
import os
path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'./static/templates')
templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath=path)
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)
TEMPLATE_FILE = "template.html"
hello="hello..... "
template = templateEnv.get_template(TEMPLATE_FILE)
outputText = template.render(value=hello)  # this is where to put args to the template renderer
print(outputText)
```

output:

```
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
</body>
</html>
@gh-laptop:~/jinja$ python app.py 
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
  <p>hello..... !</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To explain simply how `PackageLoader` works : The template folder defined (second parameter: package_path) should be relative to the folder containing the module visible from python (first parameter: package_name).

So as `APP` is not a module, you should use `app` instead. As the template folder will be relative to `APP` (the folder containing `app`) then the `package_path` is good.